# Python - How to return the indice value of a list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

Currently I have

```
 for element in initialString:
    if element == word:
      print(element.index(initialString))
```

where `initialString` is a list and `word` is a called variable.

However, it is returning a `TypeError` telling me that it cannot `convert a 'list' object to str implicity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `initialString.index(element)` (so reversed) instead; the list can tell you what index it has `element` stored in; `element` has no knowledge of the list.

You should really use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) here however, to add indices to the loop:

```
 for i, element in enumerate(initialString):
     if element == word:
         print(i)
```

If all you wanted to know was the index of `word`, however, it is simpler still to just use:

```
print(initialString.index(word))
```